# How to copy a char array to a line of a table (C)

Tags: c, arrays

I have an array of pointers, namely `char *nline[MAX_M]`. What is the most effective way to copy each `nline[i]` to the ith-line of a table `char TAB[MAX_M][MAX_N]`; I've tried

```
for (i = 0; i < M_max; i++)
    for (j = 0; j < N_max; j++)
        TAB[i][j] = *(nlinha[i] + j);
```

But it has added garbage to my table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [strncpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/):

```
for (i = 0; i < M_max; i++)
    strncpy( TAB[i] , nline[i] , MAX_N  ) ;
```

Make sure your array of pointers `nline` has valid pointers.

Answer (score 1):

to copy the ith line from nline use strcpy.

If the size of TAB is different from the size of nline use strncpy to not exceed the size of TAB.

If using strncpy, make sure to add `'\0'` to each line to make control of the TAB array (The `'\0'` indicates the end of the string).

```
strncpy(TAB[i], nline[i], MAX_N);
TAB[i][MAX_N-1] = '\0';
```

Comment: Correct usage of strncpy doesn't require to null terminate the string.

Comment: You'r not right strncpy is built to insert a string inside another, so it doesn't add the null charter. Check it by your self the correct way as you said.

Comment: I think what @self. meant is that we don't know whether `TAB` is supposed to act as an array of string, or as a 2D array of characters. In the second case, where array rows aren't expected to be strings, you don't need to null-terminate them.

Comment: @Medinoc No, I meant it for null term. strings. When using strncpy for full copy of the string the null char is copied as well. Thus you don't have to. It is only when you start fiddling with partial copies you start to get problems and you have to manually add the null character. Therefore you should always use strncpy for a full copy and nothing else. If you have to splice/edit a string you use snprintf. If you have to manually add a terminator to a string( not an array) in C you are doing something wrong. Please note this is my opinion, I'm not trying to convince anyone.

Comment: @self. Nothing in the question guarantees, or even implies, that the strings are less than `MAX_N` characters long... or that asker has a C99-compliant compiler.

Comment: @Medinoc  Nothing in the question guarantees, or even implies, that the strings would be longer than MAX_N characters.

Comment: That "retort" is childish and ridiculous: When neither the good nor the bad case are guaranteed, the good strategy is to play it safe, rather than assume the best-case scenario.

Comment: @self If the strncpy was built only for full copy and nothing else as you said, it will be like this.

`int fullcopy(char *a, char *b){
    strncpy(a, b, strlen(a) -1);
}`
So there is no mean for the third argument.